# (function(){})(); Что это?

Tags: javascript, шаблонизаторы

Начал разбиратся с шаблонизаторами на javascript, и в примерах везде встречаю вот такую запись:

```js
(function(){
    this.var1 = function(){
    
    },
    
    this.var2 = function(){
    
    };
    
    return function(){
    
    };
})();
```

Не мог бы кто-нибудь рассказать про это. Что это, зачем нужно, как используется, в чём смысл такой записи?

Comment: А что именно непонятно? В первых скобках — определение функции, финальная пара скобок — её вызов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этот синтаксис означает, что анонимная функция сразу же будет вызвана

Comment: Это я в принципе и раньше знал, а что будет с this.var1?

Comment: @Станислав Далинин, если не ошибаюсь, this в контексте данной функции ссылается на объект window

Comment: @Станислав Далинин Данные функции(методы) наружу будут смотреть. Эквивалент window.var1 = function(){}

Comment: То есть в дальнейшем для вызова var1 достаточно писать var1(); ? И зачем нужна вторая пара круглых скобок () ?

Comment: @Станислав Далинин Основной смысл данной конструкции изолировать область видимости, своего рода модуль. В Вашем примере это не выполняется, ибо оба методы торчат наружу.

Comment: А что насчёт вторых скобок? Зачем они, как используются?

Comment: @Станислав Далинин Почитайте [JavaScript Module Pattern: In-Depth](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) и [Создание модулей JS](http://habrahabr.ru/post/231883/)

Answer (score 1):

Это так называемый [IIFE (Immediately invoked function expression / выражение мгновенно вызванной функции)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/IIFE) или же SEAF (Self executing anonymous function / Само выполняемая анонимная функция). Такой синтаксис часто используется для изоляции каких-либо данных, вот пример с обычным объявлением переменной и её объявлением в IIFE:

```js
var someVariable1 = 'Hello, first world!'

console.log(someVariable1)

(function() {
  var someVariable2 = 'Hello, second world!'
})()

console.log(someVariable2)
```

Как мы видим получается ошибка, т.к. вторая переменная объявлена в функции и глобально, доступа у нас к ней нет.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, this ссылается на объект, методом которого функция является. Если она не является методом пользовательского объекта, то this ссылается на window